# Pass an array of double as a param in xsl

Tags: xslt

I need your brilliant mind!
I have next problem: I have an xsl document and I want to pass an array as a param (or variable) to this xsl to iterate over it.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
            xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:include href="properties.xsl" />
<xsl:param name="upperLimit" />
<xsl:param name="value" />
<xsl:variable name="array" />
<xsl:template match="/">
    <Chart zdepth="60" exeTime="2" chartOrder="area,column">
        <categories>
            <category label="Jan"/>
            <category label="Feb"/>
            <category label="Mar"/>
            <category label="Apr"/>
            <category label="May"/>
            <category label="Jun"/>
            <category label="Jul"/>
            <category label="Aug"/>
            <category label="Sep"/>
            <category label="Oct"/>
            <category label="Nov"/>
            <category label="Dec"/>
        </categories>
        <dataset seriesName="budget" color="1E90FF" plotBorderColor="1E90FF" renderAs="column">
            <set value="{$value}"/>
            <set value="32800"/>
            <set value="32600"/>
            <set value="29600"/>
            <set value="32600"/>
            <set value="32600"/>
            <set value="31800"/>
            <set value="36700"/>
            <set value="29700"/>
            <set value="31900"/>
            <set value="32900"/>
            <set value="34800"/>
        </dataset>
        <dataset seriesName="sales" color="EE2C2C" plotBorderColor="EE2C2C" renderAs="area">
            <xsl:for-each select="$array">
                <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
            </xsl:for-each>

        </dataset>
        <styles>
            <definition>
                <style name="captionFont" type="font" size="15"/>
            </definition>
            <application>
                <apply toObject="caption" styles="captionfont"/>
            </application>
        </styles>

        <xsl:call-template name="properties"/>

    </Chart>
</xsl:template>
```

I have  element, in which I have  elements and I want each  have some value from "array". (something like that: ,  or even in some loop:  ).

How can I do this? Any suggestion will be very-very helpful and as soon as possible!

Thanks.

Comment: Which programming language...

Comment: Good question (+1). See my answer for a detailed description of the existing possibilities to represent an aray of doubles in XSLT 1.0 and in XSLT 2.0.

Answer (score 0):

**XSLT 1.0 and XPath 1.0 don't have anything close enough to "array of doubles".**

**In XSLT such an array can be simulated by a node-set of elements** with a single text-node child (somple content in XSD terminology), such as this:

```
<num>1.2345</num>
<num>2.2345</num>
<num>3.2345</num>
<num>4.2345</num>
<num>-.2345</num>
```

**Such a node-set can be passed as external parameter by the invoker of the transformation** and the way this is done depends on the concrete XSLT processor. For example, the way to pass parameters to `XslCompiledTransform.Transform()` are defined **[here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xsl.xsltargumentlist.aspx)**.

If the above node-set has been passed as the value of the globally defined `xsl:param` named `pDoubles`, then

`$pDoubles[$k]` selects the $k-th `num` element in the node-set and it's text-node child can be used implicitly in other expressions. For example:

`$pDoubles[1] + $pDoubles[2]`

evaluates to

```
3.469
```

**In XPath 2.0 (and thus in XSLT 2.0) there is a data-type that is much closer to an array of values -- the sequence data-type**.

**The closest to array of doubles in XPath 2.0 is a sequence of doubles (`xs:double`).** Such sequence can be passed as an external parameter to an XSLT 2.0 transformation and again the details how to do this are vendor-specific. For example how to do this for Saxon, look **[here](http://saxonica.com/documentation/xpath-api/intro.html)**.

**Do note**: Node-sets in XPath 1.0 and sequences in XPath 2.0 only *simulate* arrays -- they are not arrays and one of the most important differences is that while an array access is extremely fast (O(1)), the access to an arbitrary node /item of a node-set/sequence can be O(N).